# How to get text under <Strong> tag in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML code

```
<p>
<strong>Telephone:</strong>
 1(111)234-11111
```

I want to get the phone number under strong tag
can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: <p>
<strong>Telephone:</strong>
 1(111)234-11111
<br/>

Comment: Have you tried driver.GetText(selector)?

Comment: i have tried with .getText() method but i am only getting text Telephone, i am unable to get 1(111)234-11111 due to <strong> tag

Comment: If you have solid programming skills, you should be able to easily take the example in alecxe's answer and apply it in Java. If not, having people give you the exact code you need won't be sustainable and you should focus on improving those fundamentals (learn _programming_ fundamentals, not just a particular language!) if you want to be successful in automated testing.

Answer (score 3):

The telephone number here is a text node. And, the problem is, you cannot directly target/find text nodes with Selenium WebDriver, only regular element nodes.

But, you can though locate the whole `p` element, get the text and then extract the phone number by, for instance, splitting by `:` and getting the last part of the split. Example in Python/Selenium:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[strong = 'Telephone:']").text.strip()
phone_number = text.split(":")[-1].strip()
print(phone_number)
```

Comment: Is it deprecated comment? because currently, selenium works  well with the strong tag

Comment: @PDHide it is not the strong tag that is the issue here - it is the fact that the desired data is in the "text node" after the strong tag. Hope that is clear. Thanks.